# logging module with setters in class

Tags: python, class, logging, setter

I have a question about logging module, I'm using it in some classes and I'm wondering how I can log setters or getters. For example I have a class :

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

item_ = Item('object')
item_.name = 'New object'
```

I want here a log to say name of object has been changed. Of course, I would like avoid using `@property` and setters functions which will override my class.

Comment: Why *"of course"*? I suppose you could implement `__setattr__` to log assignments to any attributes, but is that what you want?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using @property?  That seems like the obvious way to do this.

Comment: I mean I don't want to have in my class :  
@name.setter
    def name(self, value): 
        self._name = value

because if I have lots of instances, I will have lots of setters functions. how can I implement __setattr__ ?

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively straightforward to implement:

```
class Item(object):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super(Item, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        # put logging code here
```

Do not use [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) for this.  It will not handle `@property` and other data descriptors correctly.  It will also return a read-only dictionary-like-thing if you happen to be implementing a metaclass.  If you don't know what that means, then you're not implementing a metaclass, so don't worry.

If you have multiple classes like this, you can factor this functionality out into a mixin class:

```
class LoggingMixin(object):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super(LoggingMixin, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        # put logging code here
```

Now, when you want to create a new class that needs attribute logging, simply inherit from `LoggingMixin`, along with any other base classes if necessary.

Comment: Good point on the property descriptors -- this is much more general.  He said he had several classes, though, so he still might want a logging superclass.

Comment: It's working well but the problem with that method is when I create an instance of Item like item_01 = Item('Object', 150), I will receive 2 logs of __setattr__ and it's annoying if I'm using like more than 10 parameters. EXAMPLE : [link](http://i.imgur.com/tTnsLnh.jpg)

Comment: @Darkos: You can use the same super() call in any method to bypass the logging.

Comment: @Kevin: I tried, it didn't work, can you explain  a little bit more ? I'm sorry I still begin with classes.

Comment: super() is used to call a method of a superclass, like object.  object.__setattr__ provides the default attribute setting behavior.  So the super call bypasses our logging code.